# JavaScript- cannot change style when my script in head

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get my JavaScript to work when I insert the script into the `head` or `body` elements.

Here are my examples:

---

Firstly I insert it into the `body` like [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) (*working*):

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>
    
    <script>
    document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
    </script>
    
    <p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

When I move the `script` into the end of the `body` (*also working*):

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

<p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

But when I move it into the `head` it **stops working**:

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  <script>
  document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

 <p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Make sure your script execute after the page is ready.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `window.onload` which means that it will invoke only after HTML page is loaded. Here is a quick [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) for your study . Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

Use keyword [defer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) for this:

Description of defer:

> A script that will not run until after the page has loaded.

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>
    
    <script defer>
    document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
    </script>
    
    <p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

the problem is your script in head and `p2` has not define yet

so you write script in `document.ready` its work because `script` run after document has been load

for run jquery code you need to add `jquery` library for this

link:[jquery library](https://jquery.com/download/)

or write code in

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

  <p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This will indeed solve the problem, however you need a jQuery library for this. I think your answer will be better if you explain this too.

Answer (score 3):

it is because you are calling p2 at head and it is not defined at that moment. compiler don't know where is p2 that's why it is showing undefined.

One of the solutions is to do it like below:

```
window.onload = function () { 
   document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
}
```

The above script will run when the page is loaded completely

Answer (score 2):

*"Why it does not work when I insert script in head?"*

This is because the script is trying to access a DOM object before it exists. It's one of the main reasons jQuery users tend to use `$(document).ready();` wrapped around there functions.

An older practice was to always load your script below the body of your HTML document, however [it came with it's own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/6049581).

Using `<script defer> /* your code here */ </script>` is the generally accepted method if you want your script to only execute after the document is loaded. [Alternatively, you can use an external library like jQuery and use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/6049581):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

If you do decide to use jQuery, you could also replace your current script (`document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";`) with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#p2').css({'color':'blue'});
});
```

*This however isn't necessary, just an interesting option to consider*

Answer (score 1):

When your script code is in the head tag, it is executed but the DOM element is not ready yet. So, no change occurs. For such cases always use `body.onload`, because then your script will be executed after the elements in the body is ready.

Bonus: The script will also not work if you place it in the `<body>` above the `<p>` tag.